# Laravel: Use variable file from config folder in views

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a `vars.php` file in `./config/vars.php`:

```
<?php
    return
    [
        'MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH' => 6
    ];
?>
```

I need to be able to access the variables in this file inside of other `*.blade.php` files and `*.js` files.

I have looked around but haven't been able to find an answer to this. I have tried `min: Config::get('vars.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH'),` (Full code below) but this didn't work. I think I have to do some kind of include inside my master layout file, then it will be able to be accessed in all my pages (Since they all come from the master layout base).

register.js, used for my register modal:

```
register_password: {
    validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'Password is required'
        },
        stringLength: {
            min: MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH,
            message: 'Must be at least 6 characters'
        },
        identical: {
            field: 'register_confirm',
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: can you pull out the other configs, for EX: `Config::get('session.domain');`?

Comment: Using the double :: just gives `register.js:57 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: can you pull out the other configs, for EX: `Config::get('session.domain');` in the `Controller`?

Comment: I'm not doing anything in the controllers. I thought I could just work with my variable file, the master layout, and any other views.

Comment: nope i just wanted to see if it can be use in the controller. Just put `dd(Config::get('vars.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH'));` in the controller and see its working or not

Comment: Where and in what controller? I threw `Config::get('vars.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH');` in a random controller (./app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php) inside of PHP tags, but outside the class definition - And no new errors came up in the console.

Comment: can you see your value `6` in the page?

Comment: Not sure where it's supposed to show up? I don't see a random number `6` anywhere on any pages though..

Comment: what do you see on the page? and if you can please show your codes as wel?

Comment: I see all of the stuff that should be there from my index.blade.php. I just want to add a variable file where I can change variables in that one spot, and be able to use variables in all my other blade.php files on the site.

Comment: whats `min:` in here `min: Config::get('vars.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH')`

Comment: I posted more of the register.js code above. It's a validator for the password field on the registar modal. The field has to be at minimum # length.

Answer (score 0):

Try `config('vars.MINIMUM_PASSWORD_LENGTH')` - it works for me.

If you want to use it in `.js` scripts, I guess the best way would be use cookies:

[Setting cookie with Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies)

[Reading cookie with JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

You could also generate `.js` scripts dynamically, but that's awful practice.

Comment: register.js:57 Uncaught ReferenceError: config is not defined

Comment: `config` is just a helper for `Config` isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, but newbies often have trouble with namespaces and helper works everywhere without additional setup.